# IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type LdapTemplate to LdapTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-security, websphere

I'm trying to migrate a Spring webapp from Websphere Application Server to JBoss AS, but am running into this problem when deploying:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.security.filterChains': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2' 
while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'preAuthenticationFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [3];  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'preAuthenticationFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private com.m.g.utils.WebUtils com.m.g.auth.PreAuthenticationFilter.webUtils;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'webUtils': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
private com.m.g.helper.Delegate com.m.g.utils.WebUtils.Delegate; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'delegate' defined in URL [file:/workspace/Web/WebContent/WEB-INF/core-context.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'authenticationService' defined in URL [file:/workspace/M-G-Web/WebContent/WEB-INF/core-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate' to required type 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate' for property 'ldapTemplate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate] to required type [org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate] for property 'ldapTemplate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The relevant part of Core-context.xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="authenticationService" class="com.m.g.serviceimpl.AuthenticationServiceImpl">
    <property name="wmbService" ref="wmbService" />
    <property name="authenticationDAO" ref="authenticationDAO" />
    <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO" />
     <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>
...
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="#{systemProperties['ad.write.url']}" />
    <property name="base" value="" />
    <property name="userDn" value="#{systemProperties['ad.admin.userDn']}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{systemProperties['ad.admin.password']}" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>
```

And the relevant part of AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:

```
@Component("authenticationService")
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements IAuthenticationService {
private IWMBService wmbService;

@Autowired
private IAuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO;

@Autowired
private IServiceFactory serviceFactory;

@Autowired
private CustomerManagementDAO customerDAO;

private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

@Autowired
private IProperties properties;
```

I've searched to try to figure out why this error is occurring, but I've haven't found anything that worked. This exact same code worked under Websphere, so I suspect it's something like a build path issue. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us everything relevant? I don't see a property of type `LdapTemplate` defined in your XML with the name `ldapTemplate`.

Comment: Good catch, I missed the actual ldapTemplate bean definition in the XML file. I updated it above.

Comment: You misunderstand me. The error says that Spring fails to create the `authenticationService` bean because something is wrong with one of its properties of type `LdapTemplate`. Your XML does not define a `property` of type `LdapTemplate`, so I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Also, why do you have both XML declaration for a `authenticationService` bean and a Java `@Component` declaration for a `authenticationService` bean?

Comment: Silly me, I mis-pasted the critical part of the XML. You're right, it is indeed defined there as a property. Also for the bean declaration, I did not originally write this particular part of the codebase so I am unsure why that decision was made.

Comment: I had same versions of spring-ldap-core-2.4.1.jar ar EAR level and also in WAR file in WEB-INF lib. I removed the one in WEB-INF lib by updating my pom file to change scope from compile to provided in POM thats was in WAR file. That resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out in the end. The problem was I had two different versions of spring-ldap-core in my project, which resulted in two different implementations of LdapTemplate. Removing one of the jars resolved the issue.